# Mongo + Mongoid Exception failed with error "not master"

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a simple replica set configured as follows:

- mongo1 (primary)
- mongo2 (secondary)
- mongo3 (arbiter)

It functioned correctly for around a month and then we started seeing intermittent exceptions along the lines of:

```
Moped::Errors::ReplicaSetReconfigured: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command 
@length=179 @request_id=1400 @response...>{:order=>"SwimSet"}, :update=>{"$inc"=>
{:next=>1}}, :new=>true, :upsert=>true} @fields=nil> failed with error "not master"
```

They key bit being "failed with error not master. This happens sporadically when trying to write to a collection. This is not during or immediately after a failover. Shutting the secondary down but leaving the arbiter running resolves the error but leaves us without any redundancy.

What we've tried:

- Rebuilding the secondary and re-adding it to the cluster
- Failing over to the newly built node, then rebuilding the old primary
- Upgrading to Mongo 2.6.4

Current Versions:

- Mongo Server: 2.6.4
- Mongoid: 3.1.6
- Moped: 1.5.2

Any suggestions very much appreciated as been battling with this on and off for nearly a month now.

Comment: Can you post the output of rs.status()? And your connection string?

Comment: Also, are you using secondary write concern at any point? You could be using a write concern like secondary, secondaryPreferred, or primaryPreferred that may send operations to a secondary, and the secondary hasn't been cleared to respond with slaveOk. This causes the operations to fail, giving those errors.

Comment: Have you had any success in finding the cause?

Comment: Still no luck on this one, are you also seeing the same error? If so we could potentially compare configurations to try and work out what the common element is?

Comment: Seeing a similar issue with mongo 3.0.4, use secondaryPreferred and when calling a collection "drop" action.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @moesef I am next in line with error, did you resolve this ?